# Perl program spawning multiple copies of its own program after `$exec` statement is run

Tags: perl

In my perl program on Windows 7, I am seeing some strange behavior.

In the code I am calling psftp.exe using the following code :-

```
$exec = "psftp .....";
@run = `$exec` ;
```

However if psftp.exe is missing then I am seeing something very strange and I have no explanation.

I am seeing the perl program spawn multiple perl.exe processes running their own version of my perl program.

Is there a reason for this?

Thanks.

Comment: What Perl are you running? Version and ActivePerl or StrawberryPerl or whatever?

Comment: I am using ActivePerl, perl v5.8.8

Comment: Are you using `use strict` and `use warnings`? This happens only if there is no psftp.exe, right? When i run those lines with Perl 5.18 in Windows 7 i get the expected behavior, it tells me psftp does not exist and ignores the points as it assumes them to be an argument for psftp. Can you show more of your code? Especially how you handle the contents of `@run` afterwards?

Comment: Unrelated: I suggest you change the name of that `$exec` variable especially in the title as it may very well confuse others about you using `exec $command` instead of the backticks.

Comment: Hi, DeVadder,  thanks for looking into this,  I am not near my computer but will update the post as soon as I can. Thanks

Comment: As you are new: If you ping me by putting my name with an @ in front, i will get a notification. As a sole edit does not trigger a notification, i would not see it.

Comment: @DeVadder - Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it,  I finally got back onto the box today.  I found what the problem was, buried within windows, there was a .bat file with the same name that was also triggering the same .pl to run,  the machine I was using was a legacy machine.

Comment: @DeVadder - and I apologize for wasting your time, it was a strange issue, did not realize it would be another .bat with the same name triggering it. I will try changing the code to make it more literal.

Comment: Ah, the joys of `$PATH$`. That is why i never allow myself to omit the `./` in front of local apps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use backtick if you would like to capture output and check $? to make sure it is executing properly.

```
my $cmd = "psftp .....";
my @run = `$cmd` ;
### non zero exit code 
if ($?){ 
  die "$cmd failed with $? exitstatus";
}
```

Comment: If you read the question, you will note that the Op actually used backticks. `$exec` is just the name of the variable. Also the question states that this happens when the executable to be run is not found.

Comment: May bad but my answer still good. You need to check $? to make sure that the command inside the backticks are working prroperly.

Comment: While i agree that in general it may be a good idea to do so, it still has not much to do with the Ops question as that appears to happen if the command in backticks is not found at all and the script instead launches copies of itself.

Comment: I think some information is missing from the question. I never see this behaviour, the original command may contain some special chars, like & at the end.